# substring in bash failing: syntax error near unexpected token `done'.

Tags: bash, comparison, substring

I'm trying to loop through a log file and grab a portion of a string.

The log file contains:

```
Variable_name Value
Slave_running ON
```

First I need to see if the current row contains the substring `Slave_running` (13 characters long starting at position 0).  If I get a match, then I need to test what is a character to the right of the same string (14:2).

Here's my feeble attempt to first just print the substring to console:

```
while read p; do
  echo ${$p:0:13}
done <slaverunning.log
```

This returns:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `done'.
```

What am I getting wrong with the bash substring syntax wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a syntax error, but it's not about unexpected token...

The `$p` inside the `${...}` is wrong, this should give a `bad substitution` error:

> ```
>   echo ${$p:0:13}
> ```

With that fixed, your script should work:

```
while read p; do
  echo ${p:0:13}
done <slaverunning.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the issue with your code is just a syntactical one, you don't need the `$` before `p`, only before `{`.  The below should work as expected:

```
while read p; do
  echo ${p:0:13}
done < slaverunning.log
```

That said, awk seems to be a better fit for this problem, something like this:

```
awk '/^Slave_running/ { if ($2 == "ON") { print "running"; } }' slaverunning.log
```

A great walkthrough of Bash's string manipulation functions: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation/
A good place to get familiar with Awk: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html

Comment: My bad; mistook the underscore for a space -- NVM